# Optimal settings for Teradata Utility sessions

Tags: teradata

we are using the load and unload utilities (Fastload, Mload, Fast Export, etc...) wuth the default number of sessions  ? we increased the number of AMPs now so  can we know the Optimal settings for Utility sessions ? what is the criteria to calculate this?Is it DBA task or ETL developer task?

Comment: As nowadays the number of session is controlled by Teradata's Workload Management it's a DBA task to define it. By default there are three predefined numbers for small/medium/large loads, the developer can uzilize the QueryBand to set a `UTILITYDATASIZE` indicating the size of the date being loaded.

Comment: Thanks  Dnoeth for your reply ,usually what is the factors to decide the number of sessions
# of  Pes,# of  AMP ,or/AND # of  Nodes 
We found the default configuration as following
arc default 24 sessions
fast export default 18 session
fast load + multiload default 27 sessions

Comment: The number is usually a multiple of the number of nodes to get an even distribution of sessions per node, e.g. 4 nodes -> 4 or 8 or 12. Of course after some testing (e.g. checking session usage of the TPT log) your DBAs should know the optimal number.

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth for your reply, is there any manual matrix come from Teradata during the upgrade 

For example: I have server with below configuration “12 Pes,300 AMPs;10 Nodes, and we have daily 1000 Fast loads Job , 2000 MultiLoad , 2000 Fexp , I don’t have TPT
how I can all the above factor to define the session in TASM

Comment: Run some sample loads of different sizes with different sessions and check overall speed/throughput.